# Apache reverse proxy wss to ws is throwing 502 error

Tags: php, sockets, websocket, apache2, centos7

I have configured a reverse proxy to downgrade wss to ws in apache but I'm only getting a 502 error, when I tested the socket with ws (without proxy) everything worked perfect.

I'm using the WHM apache include editor in a Centos 7 server, and configured the following rules:

```
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyBadHeader Ignore
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*)/websocket_cc/ ws://MYSERVER:9000/
ProxyPass "/websocket_cc/" "ws://MYSERVER:9000/" retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On
ProxyPassReverse "/websocket_cc/" "ws://MYSERVER:9000/"
```

Basically what I'm trying to configure is when I connect to this socket *wss://MYSERVER/websocket_cc/* I want to redirect via reverse proxy to *ws://MYSERVER:9000/* where a listener socket is running.

I'm new in this kind of topic so I dont know how to deal with this kind of problem properly even when I already searched a lot in Internet.
I've checked the apache error_log file and every time the server is connecting via proxy to the ws this error get logged.

> [Wed Dec 15 04:05:02.484091 2021] [proxy:error] [pid 13587:tid
> 47893828495104] [client 127.0.0.1:44246] AH00898: Unexpected Upgrade:
> websocket (expecting n/a) returned by /websocket_cc/

But I don't know if is a server error or my server socket is not working properly, because as I mentioned, with ws worked fine.

**EDIT: I found the root problem:**

The error_log file makes reference to the response header of the websocket handshake.
Apparently the proxy server cannot handle properly the response from the socket.

This is the PHP code responsible of the handshake:

```
$upgrade  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
    "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Origin: $host\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host:$port/demo/shout.php\r\n".
    "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
    socket_write($client_conn,$upgrade,strlen($upgrade));
```

Comment: Tell me about your client-side. How do you connect to the server?

Comment: I'm connecting with this line of code: var connection = new WebSocket('wss://MYSERVER/websocket_cc/');

Comment: Remove the last slash (/) and try again.